# Создание дирректории и запись в файл в internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-file

Есть следующий метод для записи в файл:

```
 void serializeEntity(Class<?> entityClass, HashMap<String, Object> entityStore) {
        String fileName = "entity_"+entityClass.getSimpleName()+".entity";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        try {
            fileOut = MyApplication.getContext().openFileOutput(fileName, 0);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            out.writeObject(entityStore);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Данный код пишет данные в файл который находится в корневой папке, насколько я понимаю. Я хочу писать этот же файл и потом считывать его но не с корневой папки, а добавить свою и писать в свою папку. Для этого я использую следующий код:

```
public boolean isDirExist(String dirName) {
    File newdir = MyApplication.getContext().getDir(dirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return newdir.exists();
}

public void createDir(String dirName) {
    File newdir = MyApplication.getContext().getDir(dirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!isDirExist(dirName)) newdir.mkdirs();
}
```

Вот тут проблема, метод `isDirExist()`-  возвращает `true` какое имя папки я б туда не передал. А метод `createDir()`  - не создает папку, или создает, но не там где я ее ожидаю потом увидить.

Вывожу список файлов я таким образом:

```
   public void printFilesList() {
        for (String file : MyApplication.getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().list()) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "FILE: " + file);
        }
    }
```

Этот метод показывает мне все файлы которые я записывал с помощью первого метода (которые в корне) , но созданных мною папок я там не вижу.

Вопрос состоит из нескольких:

1. как создать папку
2. как потом в эту папку записать файл
3. как потом достать список папок и файлов в корне и их подпапки и файлы
4. как считать файл из подпапки.

P.S. интересует чтение/запись именно в `internal storage`, что бы у пользователя к ним не было доступа.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Запись в файл по пути /data/data/имя вашего пакета/имя папки/имя файла */
public void writeToFileInYourFolder(byte[] someData, String internalFolderName, String internalFileName) {
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    // путь к папке
    final File internalPath = new File(getBaseContext().getDir(internalFolderName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath());

    // создание папки, если не существует
    if (!internalPath.exists()) internalPath.mkdirs();

    // файл для записи
    final File internalFile = new File(internalPath, internalFileName);

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(internalFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(someData);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e("LOGTAG", exception.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.